# How to scroll an item inside a scrollable div to the top

Tags: jquery

I have a #contact-list-scroller div that scrolls in the page. Based on a contact_XXXX ID I'd like the #contact-list-scroller scroll position to bet set to make sure the contact_XXX item is at the top of the page.

```
<div id="contact-list-scroller">
   <div id="contact_8965">stuff</div>
   <div id="contact_8966">stuff</div>
   <div id="contact_8967">stuff</div>
   <div id="contact_8968">stuff</div>
   <div id="contact_8969">stuff</div>
   .....
</div>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#contact-list-scroller').scrollTop($('#contact_' + id).scrollTop());
```

But that is just scrolling to the top. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: same issue, `position().top` doesn't work everytime, found any solution ?

Answer (score 30):

I think you'll need [position()](http://api.jquery.com/position).top. Because the values returned by position() are relative to its parent (unlike offset()), it makes your code more flexible. If you change the position of your parent container your code won't break.

Example:

```
var contactTopPosition = $("#contact_8967").position().top;
$("#contact-list-scroller").scrollTop(contactTopPosition);
```

or animated:

```
$("#contact-list-scroller").animate({scrollTop: contactTopPosition});
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zf9s/

Comment: Strange that makes sense but isn't working in my app. Perhaps it's because I'm using absolute positioning...

Comment: Perhaps because it is nt taking into account the current scroll position?

Comment: Also if it's a really long list, that ends up return a contactTopPosition of -2311 etc..

Comment: My demo is using the same css as you posted in the comments below. Are the child divs of contact-list-scroller styled in some way? Maybe a live demo I can look at?

Comment: It works initially but for some reason it doesn't work consistently and repeatedly... I added some buttons in another version of the same demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5zf9s/88/

Answer (score 21):

Even I was having same situation and wanted to scroll element to top. Now, there is direct support for this behavior.

Just use `<element>.scrollIntoView(true)` JavaScript method.

---

**Example:**

`document.getElementById("yourElementId").scrollIntoView(true);`

---

**More Info:**

Although this is experimental now, soon will get support in every browser. You could find more info on this at : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView)

Comment: I see that this answer is more than a year old, but I tried this solution today on Chrome and it works. FYI

Comment: scrollIntoView did not work for me.  I have a div that is shown when hovering over a nav item, in that div I have 2 divs.  One is just a list, the other is another div that is scrollable and has content hidden.  When they mouse over an item on the left, I want the div on the right to scroll to the section about that hovered over item.  scrollIntoView scrolls that div correctly, but also scrolls the whole page body down to the top of that div.

Comment: Old post, but since this was the second Google search result, I thought I would contribute.  Yes, this works perfectly... if you are using Jquery, simply do $(selector)[0].scrollInfoView(true)

Answer (score 2):

After trying all of the above with no success I found this at W3schools:

```js
var elmnt = document.getElementById("Top");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrollTop = $('#contact_' + id).offset().top;

$('#contact-list-scroller').attr('scrollTop', scrollTop);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/sKPSY/).

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to be working. Does it batter if #contact-list-scroller has the following CSS: position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;

Comment: You may consider using `position()` instead of `offset()`. The 1st being relative to the parent, the latter relative to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jquery scrollTo plugin - you can use it to scroll to a specific DOM element
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: Thanks but that plugin hasn't been updated in years. Is it safe?