# Fixed div with scroll top button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have fullscreen fixed div, with content from ajax query. Div is scrollable, because has a lot of content. And now, on bottom, I need a button to scroll to top of div. I try scroll with `<a href="#divId"></a>` but, this looks like doesn't work, similiary `ScrollTop()` to `div` don't work too.

Comment: I'm wondering, where's your code (HTML/JS)? Also, I believe this has been answered before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846595/how-to-scroll-an-item-inside-a-scrollable-div-to-the-top

Comment: Well for one, `ScrollTop()` will only work with a lowercase `s`. Additionally, you don't want to `scrollTop()` *to* `div`, you want to set the `scrollTop()` *of* div (to 0). Please see my answer with working example.

Comment: @Santi yes, thats works perfect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `longDiv` with your div id.

```
<div id="longDiv">Bla bla bla</div>
<button>Scroll to top</button>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('button').click(function() {
           $('#longDiv').scrollTop(0);
       });
   });
</script>
```

**Working JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/8hasscb6/

If you prefer it to be animated, you can use `.animate()`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $('#longDiv').animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/8hasscb6/1/

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<a onclick="scroll(0,0)">
```

This should go to top

Comment: @hungerstar Yes and div is fixed so he can change the input values

Comment: @hungerstar Put the code in a .html file and run it in browser.It works,I tested it,I think that jsfiddle accepts js code that is written only in its box

Comment: @hungerstar No problem,he can also use jquery for animation because he has it already